# Find the matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If *T* : $\mathbb R^{3}$$\mapsto$$\mathbb R^{3}$ is a linear transformation such that

*T* $\begin{pmatrix} 
        1 \\
        0 \\ 
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 
        3 \\
        1 \\ 
        4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$, $T$ $\begin{pmatrix} 
        0 \\
        1 \\ 
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 
        -1 \\
        -1\\ 
        3\\
        \end{pmatrix}$ , $T$ $\begin{pmatrix} 
        0 \\
        0 \\ 
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 
        4 \\
        -3 \\ 
        -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$ then $T$ $\begin{pmatrix} 
        -5\\
        4 \\ 
        4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 
        ? \\
        ? \\ 
        ? \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

---

I do not know where to start with this question, I tried doing RREF of the transformation numbers but I feel that is wrong.

Comment: Try describing $T$ as a matrix.  Hint:  The columns of $T$ are related to what information you've been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above since @Gregory already gave the answer using one method:

Given information on how $T$ acts on the standard basis, knowing $T\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\4\end{bmatrix}$ and so on, this tells you exactly how to represent $T$ as a matrix.  The columns of $T$ are quite simply the corresponding results of $T$ being applied to the standard basis vectors.

We get then $T=\begin{bmatrix}3&-1&4\\1&-1&-3\\4&3&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and so all that remains to your problem is completing the matrix arithmetic necessary.

Comment: This is the more general way to go about it, I'd actually recommend it over mine, since it only works out so easily because of the problem formulation.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\vec e_i = (0, \dots, 1, 0, \dots)$ where the 1 is in the $i^\text{th}$ position. Then note that your question is

$$ T(-5\vec e_1 + 4 \vec e_2 + 4 \vec e_3) = -5\pmatrix{3 \\ 1 \\ 4} + 4\pmatrix{-1 \\ -1 \\ 3} + 4\pmatrix{4 \\ -3 \\ -1} = \pmatrix{-3 \\ -21 \\ -12}.$$

Comment: Sorry used same vector. copy and paste gets me again. Sorry if the ending algebra is wrong, but you hopefully get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{ e_1,e_2,e_3 \}$ be the canonical (standard) basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Note that for any $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we can write $(x,y,z)=ze_1+ye_2+ze_3$. Hence $T(x,y,z)=T(xe_1+ye_2+ze_3)$, and using lineality $$T(x,y,z)=T(xe_1)+T(ye_2)+T(ze_3)=xT(e_1)+yT(e_2)+zT(e_3)$$ and by hypotesis $$T(x,y,z)=x(3,1,4)+y(-1, -1, 3)+z(4,-3,-1)=(3x-y+4z, x-y-3z, 4x+3y-z).$$
Finally, $$T(-5,4,4)=(-15-4+16,-5-4-12, -20+12-4)=(-3, -21, -12).$$